# Delete older revisions, only keeping the latest. Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, revision-control

So I'm using Tortoise SVN for my maker projects...it always includes a folder video.
the content of the video folder changes in each revision. This means each commitment means another version of a large video file.....after a few commitments, the hardrive space it comsumes is way to much...Once the project is done, I would like to keep only the latest finised revision. It there a way to delete the previous revisions?

Comment: Are you sure a version control system is the correct choice for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SVN doesn't support git-like squashing. There's no way to rewrite commit history like you can in Git.

For your use case, Daniel B pointed out that SVN might not be the best tool for your use case.